# AngularJS communication between modules

Tags: angularjs

Suppose I have two AngularJS modules, namely M1 and M2, I would like to implement the function that when a variable in M1 is changed, a function in M2 can  be invoked. My code is as follow but it does not work properly. Can anyone help to see what is wrong? Thank you.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("M1", []);
    })();

angular.module("M1")
.controller("M1-controller", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            var vm = this;

            vm.test = "";
            vm.clickFunction = function () {
                vm.test = "abc";
                $rootScope.$broadcast('value-changed', vm.test);
            };
}])


(function () {
"use strict";
angular.module("M2", []);
    })();

angular.module("M2")
.controller("M2-controller", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            var vm = this;

            $rootScope.$on('value-changed', function (event, args) {
                alert(args);
            });
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to add dependency for all modules of your angular app. 
Suppose you *myApp.js* file contains the following code and load the *myApp.js* file first.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', [
  'M1',
  'M2'
]);
```

Then load your other(M1 and M2) moudules and try to broadcast and receive from different modules. If can't make this working, please create and share a *fiddle*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add M1 module as dependency in M2 module.

```
angular.module("M2", ["M1"]);
```